# (Censor Dispenser) codecadamey challenge

Tags: python

the problem description is as follows:
Write a function that can censor any occurrence of a word from the “negative words” list after any “negative” word has occurred twice, as well as censoring everything from the list from the previous step as well and use it to censor my_str.

For example, if your function is given the text:
"I am concerned that this project is horrible, awful, and broken".

it should return:
"I am concerned that this project is horrible, XXXXX, and XXXXXX".

here is my code:

```
negative_words = ["concerned", "behind", "danger", "dangerous", "alarming", "alarmed", "out of control", "help", "unhappy", "bad", "upset", "awful", "broken", "damage", "damaging", "dismal", "distressed", "distressed", "concerning", "horrible", "horribly", "questionable"]

my_str= "I am concerned that this project is horrible, awful, and 
broken."

def censor_three(email):`
  count = 0
  for word in negative_words:
    if word in email:
      count += 1
      if count > 2:
        email= email.replace(word, 'x'* len(word))
  return email
print(censor_three(my_str))
```

the output i get is :
I am concerned that this project is xxxxxxxx, awful, and xxxxxx.

What am i missing here??

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behavior you're seeing is that the loop iterates in order through the list of negative words, not the words in the text.  The list contains those negative words in the order "concerned" > "awful" > "broken" > "horrible"; this is why "broken" and "horrible" (the 3rd and 4th words from the list that it finds in the text) are censored, but "concerned" and "awful" (the 1st and 2nd words) are not.

Here's a version that iterates through the text:

```
# We'll use this package to do regex replace on the text
import re

negative_words = ["concerned", "behind", "danger", "dangerous", "alarming", "alarmed", "out of control", "help", "unhappy", "bad", "upset", "awful", "broken", "damage", "damaging", "dismal", "distressed", "distressed", "concerning", "horrible", "horribly", "questionable"]

my_str = "I am concerned that this project is horrible, awful, and broken."

def censor_three(email):
  count = 0
  # Iterate over words in the text.
  # re.sub removes punctuation; str.split splits on space to produce a list of words
  for word in str.split(re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z ]", "", my_str)):
    # Now check if the word from the text is in our list of negative words
    if word in negative_words:
      count += 1
      if count > 2:
        email= email.replace(word, 'x'* len(word))
  return email
print(censor_three(my_str))
```

Comment: Hi
your code is working, but i just don't understand couple of things and i would appreciate if you could explain it to me:

the first is this part:

`# We'll use this package to do regex replace on the text
import re.`

the second is this part:
`str.split(re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z ]", "", my_str))`

Comment: `import re` imports a regular expression library (useful for removing punctuation).  `re.sub()` uses a regular expression to remove punctuation from `my_str` (anything other than a letter or a space).  `str.split()` applies to the result of `re.sub()` and splits it on spaces, producing a list of individual words.